# How can I stop networkx to change the source and the target node?

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I make a Graph (not Digraph) from a data frame (Huge network) with networkx.
I used this code to creat my graph:
nx.from_pandas_edgelist(R,source='A',target='B',create_using=nx.Graph())

However, in the output when I check the edge list, my source node and the target node has been changed based on the sort and I don't know how to keep it as the way it was in the dataframe (Need the source and target node stay as the way it was in dataframe).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the order has changed, check out `nx.OrderedGraph`

Comment: It didn't work. for example, my source node is 400 and my target is 1. However, after creating the graph it becomes (1,400) and I need my output be (400,1)

Comment: why dont you just use transpose? or in your case does doing `nx.from_pandas_edgelist(R,source='B',target='A',create_using=nx.Graph())` cause any problems along the way?

Comment: As I explained it changes the order of source and target. In my dataframe the source node number is 400 (first column) and the target is 1(the other column in data frame). however, in the edge list, it's (1,400).

Comment: then I dont know what you mean by "based on the sort" here: "However, in the output when I check the edge list, my source node and the target node has been changed based on the sort"

Comment: by "based on the sort' I mean that the degree of the source node is 3 so it connected with 3 other nodes. However in my dataframe only once the node 1 is as the source and in the other two, it is the destination. so the edge list should be like (1,2) (400,1) (700,1) but the problem is that when I create my graph from source and node column of dataframe it changes the order and the output is (1,2)(1,400)(1,700)

Comment: you might want to add this to the question, it clarifies quite a lot. If edge order is important, I think you need to use Digraph. Otherwise Graph assumes if you have a connection from 400 to 1, then you also have a connection from 1 to 400

Comment: The problem is that I don't want it to be Digraph

Comment: then you need a "hack" because I dont think thats how networkx is intended to work, and I dont know how to do that sorry. Digraph is for situations where edge directionality (=edge order) is important as far as I know. Also I'm bit curious about the reason you dont want to use it

Comment: my network is enormous which changing it to Digraph makes the calculation impossible.

Comment: I had the same problem once with networkx. If you need to do calculations I'd recommend using `igraph` much ( *much* ) faster. if you need nice plots, then networkx has better support though (IMHO)

Comment: So there is no way to keep the  edge order as a graph with networkx

Comment: well, not that I know of. I'm sure you can find a hack around, maybe even by modifying the original library (although it could break things as well so I dont know). Or maybe there *is* a straightforward way that I'm not aware. but in any case, given your description, your real problem seems to be about using networkx in a computationally intense project. at least in my opinion.

Comment: I'll try to find a way. Thank you.